# SIMO for the binary message

Tags: digital-communications

Normally, the SIMO system sum is applied on reception. For example for a Gaussian channel with $p \in [1,R]$ antennas we have: $$r_p(t)=s(t)+n_p(t)$$ with $n(t)$ the gaussian noise.  $$s(t)=\sum_{k=1}^N a_kg(t-kT)$$ with $a_k$ the BPSK symbol, $N$ the symbol number and $g(t)$ the pulse shaping filter.

After matched filter, we have: $$\hat{a}_{k,p}=a_{k,p}+n'_{k,p}$$ where $n'_{k,p}$ is the gaussian noise.

And now, we use the Simo and from the Law of Large Numbers we have: $$\sum_{p=1}^R n'_{k,p}=0$$

My question: Is it possible to do the demodulation and after the sum? More precisely, after demodulation I have $$\hat{b}_{k,p}=b_{k,p}+\epsilon_{k,p}$$ where $\epsilon_{k,p}$ is a random perturbing term and $\hat{b}_{k,p},b_{k,p} \in \{0,1\}$. $\hat{b}_{k,p}$ is a Bernouilli variable. After the NRZ encoding, we have a new random variable $$Y_p=2\hat{b}_{k,p}-1=2(b_{k,p}+\epsilon_{k,p})-1.$$ After the sum, we have: $$\sum_{p=1}^R Y_p=2\left(\sum_{p=1}^R \hat{b}_{k,p}\right)-R=2\left(\sum_{p=1}^R b_{k,p}+\epsilon_{k,p}\right)-R$$

But how to have $$\sum_{p=1}^R \epsilon_{k,p}-R=0?$$

Answer (score 1):

> Normally, the SIMO system sum is applied on reception

I hope you mean a *complex weighted sum*! Because, if we assume the channels are uncorrelated and if we assume a Rayleigh fading channel, then the expectation of the individual channel coefficients is null, and so, in expectation, just summing all observations isn't useful. (This is different if you know all channels to be e.g. Rician, or assume correlation, but this is not the case for what you'll learn about SIMO for a start.)

> for a Gaussian channel with $p \in [1,R]$ antennas we have: $r_p(t)=s(t)+n_p(t)$ with $n(t)$ the gaussian noise.

No, when you say Gaussian *Channel*, you mean that the channel (coefficient) is Gaussian distributed, not just the noise. Otherwise, you're not really having much of a useful SIMO channel, to be honest: there's no diversity if all channels have the coefficient 1.

So, a model that I would call "Gaussian" would look like:

$$r_p(t)=h_p s(t)+n_p(t), h_p\sim\mathcal{CN}(0;\sigma_{h}^2), n_p\sim\mathcal{CN}(0;\sigma_{n}^2), \text{independent}$$

(I'm assuming all individual TX-RX channels have the same statistics and the noise is the same for all receivers; if that's not the case, you get some ${}_{h,r}$ or ${}_{n,r}$ indices to deal with the differences individually.)

So, not only your noise  adds up, on expectation, to zero, but also your $h$-weighted received signals. In that case, you're not making your observation better, inherently. In fact, since
$$\operatorname*{Var}\left(\sum\limits_{p=1,\ldots,R} h_p\right)=R \sigma_h^2,$$

you're making a channel that *varies* more – for the better or worse of it! You can then of course divide the result by $R$, which has a $1/R^2$ effect on variance, so you come out of this with a "sum channel" that varies less, but it varies less around 0, don't know whether that's what you want.

But let's assume *your* channel model: if we use that, we have a sum between a Bernuoulli and a normal variable (the sum of uncorrelated Gaussian random variables is Gaussian random variable with the sum of the expectations (variances) as expectation (variance)). That's the same problem as decoding a SISO transmission: Symbol + AWGN (which is why I'd argue the channel you describe isn't really SIMO).